# How to trigger four jQuery media queries

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, hover, media-queries

So I have 4 media queries, how might I go about triggering these. So far they are gunking up the rest of my script.

```
function checkPosition() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 787px)').matches) {
        $('.box').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.project').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ height: "100%" }, 400);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.project').animate({ height: "66px" }, 200);
            }
        );
    } else if(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 788px) and (max-width: 979px;)').matches) {
        $('.box').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.project').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ height: "100%" }, 400);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.project').animate({ height: "83px" }, 200);
            }
        );
    } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 787px)').matches){
        $('.box').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.project').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ width: "100%" }, 400);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.project').animate({ width: "150px" }, 200);
            }
        );
    } else {
        $('.box').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('.project').filter(':not(:animated)').animate({ height: "100%" }, 400);
            }, function() {
                $(this).find('.project').animate({ height: "76px" }, 200);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I really want to trigger the same height, but then go back

Comment: instead of `if else` use `else if`  :)

Comment: corrected! lol! (but still not working...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here is a lot of refactoring you can do to make this code more efficient (and thereby easier to debug). The four blocks of code are each 99% similar. Also, your second media query has an `;` that doesn't belong there, breaking that one.

This would be a lot more efficient:

```
function checkPosition() {
    //default value so you don't need the last 'else' clause
    var height = 76; 

    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 787px)').matches) {
        height = 66;
    } else if(window.matchMedia('(min-width: 788px) and (max-width: 979px)').matches) {
        height = 83;
    } else if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 787px)').matches){
        height = 150;
    }

    setHeight(height);
}    

function setHeight(height) {
    $('.box').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).find('.project').animate({ height: "100%" }, 400);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.project').animate({ height: height + "px" }, 200);
        }
    );
}

checkPosition();
```

This seems to work, however you'll also need to trigger the checkPosition every time the browser width changes (to re-check which of the media queries matches). You can do that by using this function:

```
$(window).resize(checkPosition);
```

If this still doesn't work please provide a functional example of your code, for example on http://jsfiddle.net